# Resharper - Search For Instances Of Type

Tags: resharper

Is there a way for me to ask Resharper to find all instances of a given type or interface?  I need to do a quick search for everywhere we're using an IDataReader.

[Edit]
To clarify, I'm wondering if it's possible to identify explicit and implicit usages of the type.  So `IDataReader x = GetDataReader()` as well as `var y = GetDataReader()` should be in the results.

Answer (score 3):

Right-click on an IDataReader somewhere in your code and select "Find Usages" or "Find Usages advanced". Or is there something I am missing?

Comment: Yea, that gets me part of the way there, but I'm pretty sure that it only searches for textual or explicit usages of the type.  Data readers are one of those things that get referenced with 'var' a lot in our code.  So ideally, I'd also be able to pick up instances of 'var dr = GetDataReader()', without having to search all usages of GetDataReader() as well.  If I'm wrong, I'd be happy to be so.

Comment: It isn't a textual search. R# searches for instances of the type. So it should work in your case

Comment: No matter how I perform a 'Find Usages' or 'Find Usages Advanced' I'm not able to see the implicitly typed instances.

Comment: Yes, it currently doesn't work :( I had thought it does. gorohoroh is correct.

Answer (score 2):

This is not currently possible with ReSharper. Here's a [report on this problem](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/RSRP-199152) in ReSharper issue tracker - please feel free to vote for it.
There's almost no chance we can fix it for the upcoming version 6.0 though.

A workaround may be or may not be possible depending on your specific code base - for example, you could configure ReSharper's Code Cleanup to change "var" to explicit type usage, and follow that by searching for usages but I'm not really convinced you want to do that straight away. Another way would be to search for usages of GetDataReader() but chances are you have multiple methods returning this type.

All in all, that's quite an unfortunate limitation of ReSharper.

Answer (score 0):

You can work-around this missing feature using structural search.

- Open dialog with VS menu -> ReSharper -> Find -> Search with Pattern
- Make sure `C#` is selected on the top of the dialog
- Type `var $identifier$ = $expression$;` into the editor box to look for declaration statements with implicit type
- On the right side of the dialog, double click the `expression` placeholder to edit its meaning
- Set the topmost combobox to `Expression Placeholder`
- Set the expression type to the type you are looking for
- Press OK to go back to the pattern editor
- Press `Find` to do the actual search.

This method is way more complicated than pressing Alt+F7 on the type name in the declaration. Still, you can do it if you are desperate.